# Sort function in Python is bugged?

Tags: python-3.x, sorting

I know this doubt looks quite easy but i just cant get my head to wrap around it.
I was just fooling around with python sorting, when i noticed this.

If I gave in the input as `21 ,8, 4`. The output i would receive would be `21, 4,8`. Not `4,8,21`. What i am assuming is that python is only taking the first digit and comparing, but that is not what i want. How do i fix this problem?

```
lst=list()
i=0

while i < 3:
    number=input("Give me a number: \n")
    lst.append(number)
    i=i+1
    print("\n")

lst.sort()

print("The list of ordered numbers are:")
for j in lst:
    print(j)
```

[Terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ij0a7.png)

Comment: You're sorting *strings*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)

Comment: To get input as integer, you need to do this, `int(input('You text'))`. By default `input()` only gives out `string,` as said correctly by @jonrsharpe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only mistake you are making is by taking input as string,

The line `number=input("Give me a number: \n")` should be `number=int(input("Give me a number: \n"))`

If you use `input()` only then it takes every input as string, you need to convert that to `int` in your case, using `int()`

Answer (score 0):

The sort function works on both integers and strings.
But if you want it to be implemented for the integers, you need to accept the input as integers for which you can use something like this.

```
lst=list()
i=0

while i < 3:
    number=int(input("Give me a number: \n"))
    lst.append(number)
    i=i+1
    print("\n")

lst.sort()

print("The list of ordered numbers are:")
for j in lst:
    print(j)
```